# How to perfectly combine C++ exception handlers with C libraries?

Tags: c++

I try to use libcurl in a C++ program:

```cpp
size_t getContainersCallback(const char *buff, size_t size, size_t buff_size, void *data) {
    char newBuff[buff_size + 1];
    memset(newBuff, 0, buff_size + 1);
    memcpy(newBuff, buff, buff_size);
    static_cast<string *>(data)->append(newBuff);
    return size * buff_size;
}

int main() {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    string responseBody{};

    ...

    if (curl_easy_perform(curl) == CURLE_OK) {
        json j = json::parse(responseBody.c_str());
        ...
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

But when the data obtained is not complete json, the function `json::parse` will throw an exception, causing the pointer `curl` to not be recycled.

The following method feels too stupid and forces me to write one more line of code:

```cpp
try {
    json j = json::parse(responseBody.c_str())

    ...
    
} catch (exception &e) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    throw e;
}

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

When using other C libraries, you should also encounter similar problems. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    json j = json::parse(responseBody.c_str())
} catch (exception &e) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

I don't think you need `curl_easy_cleanup` inside the catch, since you're recovering from the exception, then the function will be called twice.

---

This is not a specific issue with `C`, ifcleanup you have an exception, there are cases where not everything is cleaned up correctly, and you have to be careful in those cases.

If you really want to have something that works well with exceptions, you need to either do how you started, sprinkle `try` statements when needed.
You can write a wrapper around the `curl` objects, which will handle cleanup through RAII.
Or you can use an existing wrapper such as http://www.curlpp.org/.

Comment: Sorry for the problem in the example I gave and has been modified, but your suggestion is a good suggestion. I want to apply Java's exception handling model to C++, which seems to be a very stupid idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should use destructors to handle resource freeing. `std::unique_ptr` is flexible enough that you can repurpose it:

```
// include curl, etc.
#include <memory>

struct CurlDeleter {
  void operator()(CURL* p) const noexcept {
    if (p) {
      curl_easy_cleanup(p);
    }
  }
};

using CurlPtr = std::unique_ptr<CURL, CurlDeleter>;

int main() {
  CurlPtr curl{curl_easy_init()};

  // ...

  if (curl_easy_perform(curl.get()) == CURLE_OK) {
    json j = json::parse(responseBody.c_str());
    // may throw, doesn't matter
  }

  // curl_easy_cleanup is called automatically
}
```